# using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; not found after download and install OPD.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, batch-file, oracle11g

I have visual studio 2012 and Oracle 11g and want to connect oracle database using OPD.NET
.I downloaded the

ODAC112040Xcopy_32bit zip file and un zip the file and click the intall.bat and configure.bat then I Open the visual studio 2012 and add refrence

ODAC112040Xcopy_32bit\odp.net4\odp.net\bin\4
Oracle.DataAccess.DLL

and add in DAL.CS file
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

but the type or namespace oracle could not found.Please guide me How I solve this problem

Comment: For what it's worth the paid version of DevArt dotConnect does not require the Oracle client at all, and you can localize the assemblies, making the footprint of your application very small, for client applications.  If your company is paying the bills, it's worth a look.

Answer (score 3):

You can install ODP.NET via NuGet. Right click on solution and click on `Manage Nuget Packages` and Search for `ODP.NET`. You can choose `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` or `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` depending on your need.

You can use Package Manager console to install what you want

```
PM> Install-Package odp.net.managed
```

If you are using `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` for your build then make sure your server environments have oracle client installed. If you really want to get rid of the version conflicts for `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` between your build version and server then better rely on `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`  which you can deploy under your `bin` folder of your application.

Comment: It worked but when i click start i get this error:  `+this._connection null System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection`

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the Oracle Client.  You would have something in a directory like C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1  Oracle installs some dll's and things in the gac that is required as well as the odp.net stuff I believe.  [Does ODP.NET require Oracle Client installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819861/does-odp-net-require-oracle-client-installation)

Comment: Yes, you're right. You can't just copy and paste Oracle.DataAccess.dll. OP can try to connect through sqlplus to see if it works.