# Why has the odp.net.managed package on nuget dissapeared

Tags: nuget

It was there yesterday and now its page is completely gone. A bunch of my builds straight up started failing, I didnt think that nuget removed packages.

Is there any way I can find out why its just completely gone?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.managed/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that is one of the NuGet packages that Oracle asked Microsoft to remove from nuget.org.

Oracle identified some NuGet packages that were using their software or made it look as though they were from Oracle and asked Microsoft to remove them.

There is a [Package Content and Removals blog post](http://blog.nuget.org/20151007/Package-Content-and-Removals.html) about this which includes information about what NuGet packages should be used instead:

> If you are looking for the official Oracle software, they ask that you please download the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess package or the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework package to work with the Oracle database using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed. Somehow Oracle removed their nuget package `odp.net.managed` causing a lot of headaches among developers relying on it.

However, you can use the package [`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) which offers the same functionality.

In normal situations, permanently removing a nuget package from nuget.org is **not** supported ([source](https://docs.nuget.org/create/deleting-packages)). I guess Oracle explictly forced the nuget.org team to remove it for reasons unknown (maybe licensing?).